# Why am I getting error no result to fetch

Tags: python

I checked previous answers, I have not used fetchall twice
Also the execute part only works when I use it in SQL
#Below is literally the whole code
import mysql.connector as sqql

```
db=sqql.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user="root", password="Abhim123&", database="carrecords")
mycursor=db.cursor()
mycursor.execute="SELECT * FROM cardetails"
res=mycursor.fetchall()
db.close()
print(res)
```

Comment: `mycursor.execute="SELECT * FROM cardetails"` → `mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM cardetails")`

Comment: Thanks a lot
That was a silly error on my part.